# adjust query for empty fields

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, dataset

In Visual studio I'm doing

```
SELECT calendar.info, …. ,
calendar.ino AS Expr1, doss.dosno
FROM calendar INNER JOIN
doss ON calendar.ino = doss.ino AND calendar.ino = doss.ino
WHERE (calendar.b_date >= @cboDateFrom) AND  (calendar.b_date <= @cboDateTo) AND 
calendar.aguv like @cboUitvoerder)
```

which works, but what if `@cboUitvoerder` would be empty, how can I make it work that it would drop the last AND so it would return all items for field aguv ?

In my code I have

```
private void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string x = cboUitvoerder.SelectedItem.ToString();
        this.calendarTableAdapter.Fill(this.togaDataSet.calendar, this.cboDateFrom.Value.Date, this.cboDateTo.Value.Date, x);
    }`
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you do something like:

```
WHERE (calendar.b_date >= @cboDateFrom) AND (calendar.b_date <= @cboDateTo) 
AND
((@cboUitvoerder IS NULL) OR (calendar.aguv LIKE @cboUitvoerder))
```

Comment: then I got : Error : The best overloaded method match for 'WindowsFormsApplication3.TogaDataSetTableAdapters.calendarTableAdapter.Fill(WindowsFormsApplication3.TogaDataSet.calendarDataTable, System.DateTime, System.DateTime, System.DateTime)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Ok... does the SQL part work? this may be two separate issues. Have a look at your build-time error messages is there additional info to this error - often there is a secondary message that tells you which method parameter is not correct. It looks to me like you either have too many params or you have an incorrect type for one of the params.

Comment: The above SQL is correct and would not cause that error.  The error indicates you are not passing in correct or enough parameters to the fill method on the table adapter.  I suspect this is because the param that maps to cboUitvoerder is a date time you you cannot pass in null for it.

Comment: I solved it by not changing my sql and doing this :
 
string x ;
            if (cboUitvoerder.SelectedItem == null)
            {
                x = "%%";
            }
            else
            {  x = cboUitvoerder.SelectedItem.ToString(); }
                            
           
            this.calendarTableAdapter.Fill(this.togaDataSet.calendar, this.cboDateFrom.Value.Date, this.cboDateTo.Value.Date, x);

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the sloution from Dr Rob, but if you want to pass null as a @cboUitvoerder, you should use DBNull.Value instead c# null.